# Deploying a JSR 286 portlet on Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

Is it possible to deploy any JSR 286 complaint portlet and not specifically Liferay portlet (created using eclipse plugin etc) without any changes in project files or directory structure?

If it is not possible, are there any step by step procedure to convert any portlet to a Liferay compatible portlet?

Comment: Did you get how to deploy? 
I too have the same problem and searched link below link but didn't get. so please give me any other links or videoes related to Deploying a JSR 286 portlet on Liferay.i have googled I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible: you just need to deploy the WAR file in your Liferay deployment dir or through the interface. Some time ago I wrote a tutorial about portlets, created some JSR 286-compatible ones and deployed them. [Maybe they can help you](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/sea-portlets-exemplo/src). (Note, however, that for exploring some properties of Liferay these portlets has no `web.xml` descriptor - they will work in Liferay, but not elsewhere. Just add the descriptor if needed).

Comment: I too have the same problem and searched link you have given but didn't get. so please give me any other links or videoes related to Deploying a JSR 286 portlet on Liferay.i have googled I dint get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, due to bug [LPS-60897](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-60897)  in Liferay's resources importer module, this will not work as advertised (at least in Liferay 6.2).
See also [the forum thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/64337477#_19_message_64332622) that led to the bug report.